# JsonUnwrapped annotation behaves differently with gson and fasterxml objectmapper

Tags: java, gson, objectmapper, fasterxml

In my java project i am using XMLMapper to unwrap XML and get the output as json

Input XML:

```
<root>
<name>testName</name>
<town>testCity</town>
</root>
```

Java code

```
public class TestClass {
 @JsonAlias("name")
 private String name;
 @JsonUnwrapped
 private Address address;
}

public class Address {
 @JsonAlias("town")
 private String city;
}
```

When serialised

Gson produces below output

```
{
 "name":"testName",
 "address":{
 "city":"testCity"
 }
}
```

While objectmapper produces

```
{
 "name":"testName",
 "city":"testCity"
}
```

Is there any objectmapper option that i can get gson like output?

GSON version: 2.10.1
Fasterxml version : 2.14.0

Comment: This behavious is caused by `@JsonUnwrapped`. Is it possible to remove it?

Comment: If i remove @JsonUnwrapped annotation, the serialisation doesn't happen for address class.

Comment: Do your classes have getters/setters?

Comment: Yes it has @Data from lombok which includes getters and setters

Comment: Then we would need the *complete* configuration of `ObjectMapper` to reproduce. The defaults will not cause the described behaviour.

Comment: Can u share your tried example code link please

Comment: Literary default configuration - `new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(obj)`.